# How can I run a Django app and a Vue on the same port?

Tags: python, django, linux, vue.js

I'm building a SPA using Django for my backend and Vue to handle the entire frontend. The two apps are completely separated and they will communicate using JSON, so Django acts as an API. In order to avoid some security issue and keep using the standard Django session authentication, I'm going to run these two apps in production on the same sever and on the same port, and I will set up NGINX to route traffic, so that `/account/login` will be handled by Django while `/app/someURL` is redirected to the Vue application.

How can I do the same locally, during development? If I run `manage.py runserver` and `npm run serve -- ---port 8000` the two apps will clash because there is no way to know where should each request be redirected.

Comment: You can configure vue to build to the static folder in django so the djangos server will serve both

Comment: During development you don't need to run them both on the same port, use a _proxy_ to send requests from the frontend dev server to the backend. E.g. see what I've done [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture) (it's a Node server and React client, but the _principle_ is the same).

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to mention that i'm not rendering the Vue app from Django, so the two apps are completely seprated and Vue talks with Django using JSON

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's true, but unfortunately running them on the same port exposes some problems that i won't have when running the app in production on the same port using Nginx. The biggest problem is that when they are on two different ports, Django considers the Vue app to be on a different server, which creates a lot of problem with Sessions and CSRF tokens

Comment: The proxy configuration should be able to overcome that, it's unclear what you've done or what the specific problem is.

Comment: Let me explain: in production i will have Nginx routing requests according to the URL. In development, from my local, i don't, so if i run Vue and Django on the same 8000 port, they will clash. The solution is to run them on two different ports like 8000 and 8080 but if i do that Django considers Vue to be in a different server, and it creates a lot of problems

Comment: My question is: can i run them on the same port and route traffic locally just in the same way i would do it in production?

Comment: *"I'm going to run these two apps in production on the same sever and on the same port"* - no, you aren't, you're going to use NGINX as a reverse proxy. Why not use the same configuration locally? It's not entirely clear what you imagine "the Vue application" means in prod, because typically that should just be static assets; you could actually serve them from NGINX itself.

Comment: I was thinking that, for some reason, i could not use the reverse proxy when i'm accessing the two apps from the same machine and not from "outside". What do you mean when you say "you aren't"? If i use nginx as a reverse proxy, aren't the two apps running on the same port but Nginx "decides" where is each request redirected?

Comment: *"aren't the two apps running on the same port"* - no. *NGINX* is running on that port and proxying requests to the other apps, running on two additional *different* ports, according to the path. You can do exactly the same thing locally.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot for making it much more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to run both apps on same port using Nginx, the the option is to use two  [locations](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/#configuring-locations) to redirect your requests. Something like:

```
location /serverA/ {
...
proxy_pass http://serverA:port/;
...
}

location /serverB/ {
...
proxy_pass http://serverB:port/;
...
}
```

This will only work if servers have unique IP.

Answer (score 1):

As you use npm just to serve the static content, you can easily serve the Vue app with the Django backend. If you want some pages to be rendered by Django and others by Vue, then you could create two base templates: one for pure Django pages and one for pure Vue pages that may use the vue-router library for routing.